# express-ws: How to avoid typing the port on the request url?

Tags: node.js, express, port, ws

I've successfully created a WS Server using Node.js and wxpress-ws. The problem is that I don't know which port to use to not type it in the request URL. So, instead of using *ws://mysite.com::xxxx/*, I need to be able to type only *ws://mysite.com/*

I've tried to listen port 80, 8080, without success.

Comment: check out this answer for indirect approach https://superuser.com/questions/111685/how-can-i-specify-ip-and-ports-for-a-hostname-in-the-windows-hosts-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is listening on port XXXX then you will need to access it via indicating the port in your url ws://myapp.com:XXXX/.

If you want to use ws://myapp.com/, you will need to listen to the port 80, two solutions for you :

- Launch your application with `sudo node myapp.js` privileges and make it listen on port 80. I don't recommend this approach since it might introduce some vulnerabilities because the app is running with admin privileges.
- Set up some reverse proxy like `nginx` that will listen on port 80 and that will redirect the traffic to your application listening on port XXXX. You can find a lot of tutorials online